# __VA_ARGS__ runtime equivalent?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, equivalent, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make a function similar to this:

```
#define printf_copy(s, ...)  printf(s, ##__VA_ARGS__)  // acceptable!
```

but that's a preprocessor, I need one for runtime, like this:

```
+ (NSString *)format:(NSString *)first, ...
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:first, __VA_ARGS__]; // unacceptable!
}
```

BUT!! this is unacceptable by compiler!

I'm trying to figure out whats the local variable for (...)?
(yes those 3 dots)

Comment: I can't find anything in your question that is not answered by @Carl below. Care to either expound or mark his answer as accepted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's exactly the same as with C variadic functions.  That means you can't just pass it through directly, you have to pass a `va_list` around.  You'll need something like:

```
+ (NSString *)format:(NSString *)first, ...
{
    NSString *string;
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, first);
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:first arguments:args];
    va_end(args);

    return [string autorelease];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - is there a problem with this answer?

Comment: I'm a noobie, all this time I didn't know I have to press the check button as an accept-answer, ACCEPTED!